# Share image on whatsapp in Android "The file format is not supported." error

Tags: android, share, whatsapp, file-format

I have an application with share image on whatsapp in android. It was working till now.But now I get the following error

> "The file format is not supported."

Nothing changed on code.

```
btnWhatsapp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {   

        if (isAppInstalled("com.whatsapp"))   {
           // APP  INSTALLED
           Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           String sharetext ="Try my app";
           sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,sharetext );
           Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawable/"+logofilename);
           sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
           sendIntent.setType("image/png");
           sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
           v.getContext().startActivity(sendIntent);

        }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.nowhatsapp,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }                   
            }
       });
```

Comment: `android.resource` is an uncommon `Uri` scheme and may not be supported by all apps. Also, `ACTION_SEND` implementations do not have to honor both `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM` on the same `Intent`.

Comment: got the same error have you found the solution?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: I encountered the same error. Is there any solution?

Comment: any solution in 2022?

Comment: we need to make a copy for that file (from internal) to SDCard and then, we could get the File Object... 
that file object is now public and shareable throughout whatsapp. :D @Innocent

Answer (score 3):

The file you are trying to share is in the package (your app) only your app can access the file. 
You need to share a public file

```
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        Uri.parse( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator+"temporary_file.jpg"));
```

like this other app can have access

Comment: but images are in  my app drawable directory.

Comment: You could copy that drawable in to the sd card reading to bitmap and save it with new file(), share that file, and then delete it, and you will keep all clean

Answer (score 0):

you need download image from url  to sdcard and pick the path from sdcard to share to whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is facing this issue until now then I have figured it out somehow. Every directory containing the `.nomedia` file will not be available to share images/videos programmatically.

My application creates a directory in Android/media, I don't want to show all the clips in the gallery that's why I have created a `.nomedia` file programmatically but later I realised that if someone wants to share a video (on WhatsApp) using my application, the `.nomedia` file is not allowing my application to do so and eventually WhatsApp throws an error "**The file format is not supported**", it's happening on few devices. Delete this file and your app will be able to share videos. Although deleting this file is not recommended as it may flood the user's gallery with useless/duplicate clips and images but I couldn't find any other solution till now.

Answer (score -1):

```
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
whatsappIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

try {
    activity.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the permissions of your app, enable storage permissions in App permissions, it will solve your problem.